# MVC 5 create user using Identity 2 in synchronous way

Tags: asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create new user and add him to selected role. I want to do it sync way, but always get stacked at point of creating in part ModelState. If I make it without ModelState then method will stack at point adminresult where is user created with UserManager. It looks like there is a problem with adding user to selected role, but I'm not sure. I'm using Identity 2. Is it possible to create user sync way or is it totally async process?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User userViewModel, params string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User()
            {

                UserName = userViewModel.UserName,
                Email = userViewModel.Email,
                FirstName = userViewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = userViewModel.LastName,
                Password = userViewModel.Password
            };

            var adminresult = UserManager.Create(user, userViewModel.Password); // without using ModelState stack here
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

            var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);
            var result = userManager.AddToRoles(user.Id, selectedRoles);

            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (selectedRoles != null)
                {

                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        // gets all names of roles to list
                        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
                        return View("_Create");
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("UserWizardIndex");
            }
            return View("_Create");
        }
```

Comment: what are the exception messages you are getting

Comment: System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_msvvxqen.dll  occured when I try to create new user and add him to role - can has more then 1 role, when I try to create user for project (using different controller and sync action) I get ((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors role for this user is setting while creating and has onle 1 role.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use group based roles instead of giving multiple roles at login. 
Your a sync will work fine in this way if single role is at login..

> one thing that I saw in your code is if you have selected multiple
>   roles why there isn't any way to add every role against that user...

```
       // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
                (
                new RoleStore<IdentityRole>
                (
                    new ApplicationDbContext()
                )
                 );


            if (!roleManager.RoleExists(model.RoleName))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(model.RoleName));
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var role = Db.GetUserRoleId(model.RoleName);
            var strRole = role.FirstOrDefault().ToList();
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var userInfo = new UserInformation

                {

                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    GUID = user.Id,
                    RoleId = model.RoleId
                };
                Db.UserInformations.Add(userInfo);
                UserManager.AddToRoles(userInfo.GUID, model.RoleName);
                await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
                Db.SaveChanges();

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);


                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```